# 404 with URL Rewrite Module in IIS7 on windows 7

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the URL through "Using **URL Rewrite Module**" on IIS7 (windows 7).

URL: **http://localhost/AIM/group-discussion/videos.aspx?id=4&title=some-title**

Rewrite **URL: http://localhost/AIM/group-discussion/videos/4/some-title**

Rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^AIM/group-discussion/videos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="AIM/group-discussion/videos.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

I am getting 404 error while accessing rewrite URL (http://localhost/AIM/group-discussion/videos/4/some-title)

following error log through **"Failed request tracing"** in IIS7

```
MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS

ModuleName="IIS Web Core", Notification="MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="404", HttpReason="Not Found", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The system cannot find the file specified.
 (0x80070002)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""
```

I am running site in "**Integrated Pipe mode"**

Comment: If you access the destination URL directly, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Try using process monitor from www.sysinternals.com.  That will let you know what it's attempting to do on disk.  Possibly you just need a / at the beginning of your rewrite path.

If it doesn't show attempting to do anything on disk then try Failed Request Tracing.  That will provide even further details.